# Visual Studio profiler refuses to load debugging symbols from a dynamically generated assembly

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am generating an assembly dynamically at runtime, like this:

```
AssemblyBuilder = AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicAssembly(new AssemblyName(fname), AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave);
moduleBuilder = AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule(fname, $"{fname}.dll", true);
var typeBuilder = moduleBuilder.DefineType("InternalType", TypeAttributes.Public | TypeAttributes.Class, typeof(BaseClass))
var methodBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineMethod($"MyMethod", MethodAttributes.Private, typeof(int), new [] { typeof(int) })
```

I also emit debugging symbols:

```
var documentBuilder = moduleBuilder.DefineDocument(Path.GetFullPath(fileName), SymDocumentType.Text, Guid.Empty, Guid.Empty);
File.WriteAllLines(fileName, method.SourceCodeLines);

// While emitting IL
gen.MarkSequencePoint(document, lineIndex + 1, 0, lineIndex + 1, method.SourceCodeLines[lineIndex].Length + 1);
```

Now, whenever I profile the application (Alt+F2) and I navigate to one of the dynamically generated methods, I get a report that just says:

> Symbol file does not contain source information or cannot be found.
>   You may choose the ‘Symbol Settings…’ link to add the symbol file
>   location and then reload the report.

I've tried adding the Debug/ and Release/ directories to my symbol paths, but it seems like Visual Studio is just ignoring the `*.pdb` files in there. (I've checked, the pdb files are actuall generated & saved)

Is there any way around this?

Comment: It is explicitly mentioned in the MSDN article for MarkSequencePoint.  Quote: "If the current ILGenerator is associated with a DynamicMethod object, it does not support symbolic information."

Comment: I'm not building a `DynamicMethod`, I'm generating a proper assembly which can be saved to disk. Also the debugging symbols are available while debugging (I can set breakpoints inside the generated code), the only place where the symbols don't work is in the profiler.